# Log in with postgres DBMS users in Spring Security

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-boot, authentication, spring-security

I have the following problem, I am developing a web application with spring boot, spring security and jdbc. I need that once the user clicks on the authenticate button in the login form, my application verifies that this user is a user of my database manager, that is, I do not need a table in my database with users and encrypted passwords, but check against the managing system itself, in my specific case, pgAdmin4. If this user exists and matches the password, give them access to my website. I have searched a lot for information about this, but I can't find anything that helps me, I hope I have explained well what I want to do, and above all find help here, thanks in advance.

// This is my Spring Security configuration class

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class SpringSecurityConfig {

    @Autowired
    private CustomAuthenticationProvider authProvider;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> {
                            authorize
                                    .requestMatchers(
                                            "/css/**",
                                            "/js/**",
                                            "/vendor/**",
                                            "/scss/**",
                                            "/img/**"
                                    )
                                    .permitAll()
                                    .anyRequest().authenticated();
                        }
                ).formLogin(
                        form -> form
                                .loginPage("/login")
                                .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
                                .defaultSuccessUrl("/home")
                                .permitAll()
                )
                .exceptionHandling()
                .accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler())
                .and()
                .logout(
                        logout -> logout
                                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                                .permitAll()
                )
        ;
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(
            AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) throws Exception {
        return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Autowired
    void registerProvider(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authProvider);
    }

    @Bean
    public AccessDeniedHandler accessDeniedHandler() {
        return new CustomAccessDeniedHandler();
    }
}
```

// This is my datasource configuration class

```
@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfig {
    
    private Environment environment;

    @Autowired
    public DataSourceConfig(Environment environment){
        this.environment=environment;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource getDataSource(){
        DriverManagerDataSource driverManagerDataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        String URL = "spring.datasource.jdbcUrl";
        driverManagerDataSource.setUrl(environment.getProperty(URL));
        String DRIVER = "spring.datasource.driverClassName";
        driverManagerDataSource.setDriverClassName(Objects.requireNonNull(environment.getProperty(DRIVER)));
        String USER = "spring.datasource.username";
        driverManagerDataSource.setDriverClassName(Objects.requireNonNull(environment.getProperty(USER)));
        String PASS = "spring.datasource.password";
        driverManagerDataSource.setDriverClassName(Objects.requireNonNull(environment.getProperty(PASS)));
        return driverManagerDataSource;
    }
}
```

// This is my authentication provider class

```
@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication)
            throws AuthenticationException {

        String name = authentication.getName();
        String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();

        //Here I would like to configure a datasource with the username and password above, and check if the connection was successful, give the user access to my website, if not, ask them to write a new username and password.
        
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

It is important not to create the connection to the database before, but to configure and connect to the database in the authenticate method of the CustomAuthenticationProvider class. Thank you

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered my own question in case anyone needs something similar at some point.

Create a RoutingDataSource class, to add my data source at runtime.

```
@Component
public class RoutingDataSource extends AbstractRoutingDataSource {

    public static final int DEFAULT = 0;
    public static final int NEW = 1;

    private volatile int key = DEFAULT;

    public void setKey(int key){
        this.key = key;
    }

    private Map<Object,Object> dataSources = new HashMap<>();

    RoutingDataSource() {
        setTargetDataSources(dataSources);
    }

    public void addDataSource(int key, DataSource dataSource){
        dataSources.put(key,dataSource);
    }

    @Override
    protected Object determineCurrentLookupKey() {
        return key;
    }

    @Override
    @Nonnull
    public DataSource determineTargetDataSource() {
        return (DataSource) dataSources.get(key);
    }
}
```

Create a configuration class to initialize empty RoutingDataSource, since when initializing the project, no data sources available.

```
@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfig {

    @Bean
    public RoutingDataSource create() {
        return new RoutingDataSource();
    }
}
```

Finally, modified the authenticate method as follows.

```
@Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication)
            throws AuthenticationException {

        String URL = "spring.datasource.jdbcUrl";
        String DRIVER = "spring.datasource.driverClassName";
        String name = authentication.getName();
        String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();

        DataSource datasource = DataSourceBuilder
                .create()
                .url(environment.getProperty(URL))
                .driverClassName(environment.getProperty(DRIVER))
                .username(name)
                .password(password)
                .build();
        try {
            Connection connection = datasource.getConnection();

            routingDataSource.addDataSource(RoutingDataSource.NEW, datasource);
            routingDataSource.setKey(RoutingDataSource.NEW);

            return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                    name, password, new ArrayList<>());

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
    }
```

I don't know if it's the right way to do this, but it just worked well for me, thanks for the help.